# Trouble connecting to Amazon EC2 over SSH via mac terminal

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, terminal

I'm having inexplicable trouble connecting to my EC2 instance. I'm using the below, and no solution seems to quite be working properly. Thank you very, very much for your time!

```
ssh -v -i MikesKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-83-106-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-83-106-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.83.106.238] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file MikesKeyPair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file MikesKeyPair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 5f:f1:86:8e:86:aa:94:43:a6:fe:16:68:be:6c:e7:ee
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-83-106-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/goldnuggets/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/goldnuggets/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: MikesKeyPair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to check on the server for what sshd is logging but with the info provided my initial guess would be that the server is rejecting the keys. As to why - see the server logs  it initially I'd guess incorrect permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Iain. I'm going to try looking at this and will let you know. I don't have direct access to the ec2 server in question... but you're saying that it's not allowing permissions?

Comment: @Goldnuggets Read up on the permissions required on the relevant files and directories for ssh on both the client and the server.